# Relationship between Event Listeners and Handlers

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, addeventlistener

Suppose that I both set `xhr.onreadystatechange = handler` and call `xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', listener)` on the same XMLHttpRequest object. Which one will be called first? If the `listener` calls `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, will `handler` be called?

Is the resultant behavior specified, or is it browser implementation dependent?

Comment: `addRequestListener` is not a built-in method of the XMLHttpRequest object. Docs -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @daddygames quoting the MDN page you referenced: "More recent browsers, including Firefox, also support listening to the XMLHttpRequest events via standard addEventListener() APIs in addition to setting on* properties to a handler function." XMLHttpRequest implements EventTarget, which specifies addEventListener() method.

Comment: You didn't use `addEventListener` look at your code example. Do you see the difference in syntax?

Comment: @daddygames Ah, thank you. That was a typo. I fixed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't get an authoritative answer, I tried it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/6fkhc9om/

```
document.getElementById("basicXHRButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Loading the jQuery code
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js", true);
  request.send(null);

  // this listener suppresses onload handler
  // if this is commented out, onload handler will be invoked
  request.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    alert("load listener 1");
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(request.responseText);
    alert("onreadystatechange handler " + request.readyState);
  };

  // this listener does not suppress load event listeners or handlers
  request.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(event) {
    alert("readystatechange listener 2 " + request.readyState);
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

  request.onload = function() {
    console.log(request.responseText);
    alert("onload handler");
  };

  // this listener doesn't suppress onload handler
  request.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    alert("load listener 2");
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });


  request.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    alert("load listener 3");
  });

});
```

At least for my current version of Chrome (Version 76.0.3809.132) and Firefox (Version 69.0), I observe that setting an event handler is treated the same as adding an event listener. I.e., event listeners added *before* an event handler is set can suppress the handler using `stopImmediatePropagation()`; event listeners added *after* the handler do not suppress the handler. Also, events of one type do not suppress events/handlers of another type. E.g. a `readystatechange` listener doesn't suppress `load` listeners or the `onload` handler, even if it's registered earlier.